# Error when bulk upload to MySQL hosted on AWS

Tags: mysql, r, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mariadb

I have an established connection with MySQL hosted on AWS. 
Currently for bulk uploads I am using the DBI dbWriteTable function. The downside is, it takes 5 minutes to insert a data.frame that has 10k observations. I have decided to try and use LOAD DATA INFILE query to reduce the time it takes to upload a bulk data frame. However, I am getting an error telling me my current user id is denied from doing such commands.

Below is the code that I have tried followed by the error message.

```
library(RMariaDB)
library(DBI)

con = dbConnect(MariaDB(),
            dbname = "testing123",
            host = "********",
            user = "*****",
            password = "******", 
            port = 3306 
 )

dbWriteTable(con, "mt", mtcars)

##create a data frame that has about 6000 rows
mtcars.extended = cbind(mtcars, rep(unname(unlist(mtcars)), 20))

#use the standard dbwritetable to append the rows
dbWriteTable(con, "mt", mtcars, append = T)
###This took 5 minutes but worked

##So I decided to save mtcars.extended as a csv and try the bulk 
upload
write.table(mtcars.extended, "mtext.csv")

query = "LOAD DATA INFILE 'mtext.csv' INTO TABLE mt"

dbGetQuery(con, query)
Error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement, is_statement) : 
Error executing query: Access denied for user 'testing123'@'%' 
(using password: YES)

dbSendStatement(con, query)
 Error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement, is_statement) : 
 Error executing query: Access denied for user 'testing123'@'%' 
 (using password: YES)
```

What I would have liked to see happen is a relatively quick insert into the data table "mt" without any overwriting. But it seems AWS is not allowing me to do bulk uploads.

Thanks to  Matus, I solved the issue. The only problem is, I am getting NA 's when bulk uploading.

```
  query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'mt.csv' INTO TABLE mtcars"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that you are talking about RDS MySQL. You see that permission error when trying to perform `LOAD DATA INFILE` query simply because you don't have full root permission for RDS managed system.

You may try to run `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` instead with `--local-infile=1` flag set to true. This should work as you don't need that permissions to run this query.

Comment: Thank you for the response Matus , I am new to SQL, would you mind explaining why I would want to set --local-infile=1 ? You are correct about RDS MySQL. Also is there a way to get full root permission (as it's my database) or is that a premium service?

Comment: @JordanWrong `--local-infile=1` just enables local data loading which you need if you want to use the above mentioned query (if it wasn't enabled already). No, there is no way to get full root permissions because RDS is managed service, so they don't allow you to do everything you want. If you really need it then you can run EC2 instance and install MySQL on top of it.

Comment: Matus it worked! But for some reason, I am only getting the mpg column filled out, everything else is NA. I have edited the original post to show what is going on.

Comment: I solved the NA issue, here is the full query. "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'mt.csv' 
INTO TABLE mtcars 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;"